# "Unexpected identifier" error for first object (Safari only)

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

When I run the following code in Safari (and only Safari), the Javascript won't load in the browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let dataX = {
    last: 100
  };
  let quotes = [{
    quote: "I find it fascinating that...
```

and I get an error message: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'dataX'`

When I comment out the `dataX` object, the next object creates the same error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'quotes'` It seems that no matter what the first object is, it will throw an error in Safari.

The page displays a random quote in a simple Bootstrap container. You can find a link to the CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/halfalpine/pen/ZOqBvQ).

What I've tried so far:

- Check the inspector and Google the error message
- Load the CodePen in Chrome and Firefox (it works)
- Validate the HTML, and use a linter for the JS
- Open the `index.html` locally in Safari, with the proper `<header>` and `<meta>` tags, as well necessary Bootstrap and jQuery files.
- Google the issue both in and beyond Stack Overflow
- Comment out different functions and objects to see if it makes the page work

I suspect that the problem is not the object to which the error message refers; I also suspect the solution may be trivial. However, I am completely stumped. Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `let` keyword is [*not* supported in Safari before version 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let).

Comment: In addition to removing 'let', I had to remove use of arrow functions. Thanks  for pointing me down the road of ES6 compatibility. It's now working on both mobile and desktop Safari.

Comment: Odd. There were no arrow functions on the question